# How would I print all the instances when the "$" shows up?

Tags: python

I have this string and I'm basically trying to get the numbers after the "$" shows up. For example, I would want an output like:

```
>>> 100, 654, 123, 111.654
```

The variable and string:

```
file = """| $100 on the first line
          | $654 on the second line
          | $123 on the third line
          | $111.654 on the fourth line"""
```

And as of right now, I have this bit of code that I think helps me separate the numbers. But I can't figure out why it's only separating the fourth line. It only prints out `111.654`

```
txt = io.StringIO(file).getvalue()
idx = txt.rfind('$')

print(txt[idx+1:].split()[0])
```

Is there an easier way to do this or am I just forgetting something?

Answer (score 2):

Your code finds only the last `$` because that's exactly what you programmed it to do.
You take the *entire* input, find the last `$`, and then split the rest of the string.  This specifically ignores any other `$` in the input.

You cite "line" as if it's a unit of your program, but you've done nothing to iterate through lines.  I recommend that you quit fiddling with `io` and simply use standard `file` operations.  You find this in any tutorial on Python files.

In the meantime, here's how you handle the input you have:

```
by_lines = txt.split('\n')    # Split in newline characters
for line in by_lines:
    idx = line.rfind('$')
    print(line[idx+1:].split()[0])
```

Output:

```
100
654
123
111.654
```

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions yay:

```py
import re

matches = re.findall(r'\$(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', file)
```

Finds all integer and float amounts, ensures trailing '.' fullstops are not incorrectly captured.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it! For every character in txt: if it is '$' then continue until you find a space.

```
print(*[txt[i+1: i + txt[i:].find(' ')] for i in range(0, len(txt)) if txt[i]=='$'])
```

Output:

```
100 654 123 111.654
```

Comment: Ahhh I forgot about split() but I like my answer - why use many line when one line will do ;) (other than code efficiency...)

Comment: That works well but I have a question? I'm not the best in Python but if I said this word "helloworld" was in the string, why am I not able to look for "hello" to print `world`? I just kind of noticed it and was curious

Comment: Ahh that is a good point - I am just checking for one character at a time (`if txt[i]=='$'`). But if instead you had a variable `target = "hello"` you could change that to `if txt[i:len(target)] == target]` and adjust the beginning as well so it is starting to print after the end of `target`

Comment: That's works great too! However, there is one more issue. Sorry for this but it prints out `elloworl`

Comment: Ah yeah I had that in there too but the entire post was getting too pink to read - here is the whole line: `print(*[txt[i+len(target): i + txt[i:].find(' ')] for i in range(0, len(txt)) if txt[i:len(target)]==target])`. This is assuming that there is a space after world. The real question is what functionality you need from this line: if you want any word after `hello` then this will work but if you know that `world` is always after `hello` you could: `print(*['world' for i in range(0, len(txt)) if txt[i:len(target)]==target])`. Which is kind of silly but gets the job done! @WaddyBox

Answer (score 0):

Your whole sequence appears to be a single string.  Try using the split function to break it into separate lines. Then, I believe you need to iterate through the entire list, searching for $ at each iteration.
I'm not the most fluent in python, but maybe something like this:

```
for i in txt.split('\n'):
    idx=txt.rfind('$')
    print(txt[idx+1].split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
re.findall('\$(\d+\.?\d*)', file)

# ['100', '654', '123', '111.654']
```

The regex looks for the dollar sign `\$` then grabs the maximum sized group available `()` containing one or more digits `\d+` and zero or one decimal points `\.?` and zero or more digits `\d*` after that.